# Insert into postgres SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

Is there a way to insert a new record to a table which doesn't have an auto-increment ID without specifically entering the ID. I just want the ID to be lastId+1.

`INSERT  INTO lists VALUES (id,'KO','SPH', '5')` //new id

Comment: So you want the behavior to be like a sequence ("auto-increment"), without using a sequence. Why not? These things exist to solve problems which you would otherwise easily get into with concurrent inserts.

Comment: I just want to insert a new record without changing the DB structure...

Comment: If this is an exceptional case, alright... If this is the normal modus operandi, maybe you should be changing your database structure.

Comment: The db design is not up to me :)

Comment: Then you may have to talk to the person who it *is* up to. :)

Comment: This is insane, a sequence barely fits the definition of "database structure"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't do that! **EVER**! **Don't even think about doing that!**

This **WRONG** solution may seems (it doesn't) to work for you:

```
INSERT INTO lists VALUES ((SELECT max(id)+1 FROM lists),'KO','SPH', '5');
```

**BUT**, if someone try to insert at the same time as you, you both would get the same `id`, which will cause an invalid result. You really should use a `sequence` or some more reliable mechanism (an auxiliary table is common when you can't have holes in the sequence, but it has some drawbacks [it will lock]). You can even use `serial` data type to make it easier (it creates a sequence underneath):

```
CREATE TABLE lists(id serial, col2 text, col3 text, ...);
-- If you don't specify "id", it will autogenerate for you:
INSERT INTO lists(col2, col3, ...) VALUES('KO','SPH', ...);
-- You can also specify using DEFAULT (the same as above):
INSERT INTO lists(id, col2, col3, ...) VALUES(DEFAULT, 'KO','SPH', ...);
```

If you really, really, REALLY, can't create and use a sequence, you can do as the above, but you will have to handle the exception (assuming the `id` field is PK or UK, and using a read committed transaction), something like that (in PL/pgSQL):

```
DECLARE
    inserted bool = false;
BEGIN
    WHILE NOT inserted LOOP;
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO lists
            VALUES ((SELECT coalesce(max(id),0)+1 FROM lists),'KO','SPH', '5');
            inserted = true;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN unique_violation THEN
                NULL; -- do nothing, just try again
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

But again, I highly recommend you to avoid it: use a sequence and be happy... =D

Also, I know it is a example, but use explicit columns list on `INSERT INTO` clause.

Comment: what happens if there is no data and you do max(id) + 1 ?

Comment: @maazza: then `max` would return `NULL` (and `NULL+1` returns `NULL`), you can simple handle that easily with `COALESCE`, I'll update the answer to do that

Comment: To be fair, the warning's rather melodramatic. Providing there's a key constraint on the id attribute, the worst that will happen is that one of the inserts will fail.